# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir – /private/tmp (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: bash, macos, shell

After running some shell commands to do some cleanup on my MacBook, when I run the brew command below:

```
brew upgrade
```

I get the error below:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /private/tmp (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:578:in `mkpath'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup/config.rb:47:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup/config.rb:46:in `then'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup/config.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:8:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:22:in `require_relative'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue started after I ran the command below to clean up `tmp` folder:

```
sudo find / -not -path "/usr/local/*" -name 'tmp' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

**Here's how I resolved it**:

The error indicates that the `/private/tmp/` is not existing and that **brew** runs into a permission error when it tries to create the folder. To fix it simply run the commands below to create the required folder and apply the appropriate permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp/

sudo chown $(whoami):admin /private/tmp/
```

**References**:  [Fix my Brew](https://dennyhermawanto.wordpress.com/2021/01/31/fixed-brew/)

Comment: If `/private/tmp` didn't exist, a reboot would probably have helped as well.

Comment: Tried a reboot, but it did not work for me. Maybe I was missing something, but the commands above solved them for me.

Comment: By default, `/private/tmp` is owned by root. It may not be a good idea to `chown`.